# In Sencha Architect, how can I call a self define function?

Tags: extjs

I created a controler in Sencha Architect, and then created a function, but when I run the program, it says "TypeError: this.epoSetValues is not a function". How can I call this function?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
    refs: {
        epoTabPanel: '#epoTabPanel'
    },

    control: {
        "#epoTabPanel": {
            initialize: 'onEpoTabPanelInitialize'
        }
    }
},

onEpoTabPanelInitialize: function(component, eOpts) {
    Ext.data.JsonP.request({
                 url: 'http://192.45.1.178/str/20141027085543295a746e70bab8f1c08cbec9462f2a02256',
                 timeout: 30000,
                 callbackKey: '',
                 callback: function() { 
                 },
                 success: function(result) { 
                    this.epoSetValues(result.po_id);
                 },
                 failure: function() {
                 }
             });

},

epoSetValues: function(po_id) {
            Ext.getCmp('po_id').setTitle(po_id);
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `this` scope is different inside `Ext.data.JsonP.request`. It is scoped to `Ext.data.JsonP`. Do it like this:

```
var me=this;
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
             url: 'http://192.45.1.178/str/20141027085543295a746e70bab8f1c08cbec9462f2a02256',
             timeout: 30000,
             callbackKey: '',
             callback: function() { 
             },
             success: function(result) { 
                me.epoSetValues(result.po_id);
             },
             failure: function() {
             }
         });
```